# how to group several columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to analyze chines GDP according to its provinces. I want to make a line chart that shows changing GDP over time but I cannot group them.
i want to pivot the table but it is not working as I want.
[image]

**but I want to make it like this**
[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex]. Screenshots of code/data don't quite work here.

Comment: `df.set_index("Year").T`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to switch x and y axes. Use [`transpose`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html). You can call it with `T`.

```
transposed_df = df_data.T
print(transposed_df)
```